# How to select an item property in a drop list using Sitecore 8.2 and Glassmapper

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

it's been a while since I've used Sitecore and I'm struggling with an issue.

There is a model which is being autogenerated by TDS and uses Glassmapper for its mapping.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.TemplateIdString, Cachable=false)]
public partial interface IParametersTemplate_Panel : IGlassBase 
{
    [SitecoreField(IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.BackGroundColorFieldName)]
    Guid BackGroundColor {get; set;}

    [SitecoreField(IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.HasBackgroundColorFieldName)]
    bool HasBackgroundColor {get; set;}
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public static partial class IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants
{
    public const string TemplateIdString = "cbecbd24-8b2d-4694-a4f2-aa888b385cfc";
    public static readonly ID TemplateId = new ID(TemplateIdString);
    public const string TemplateName = "ParametersTemplate_Panel";

    public static readonly ID BackGroundColorFieldId = new ID("7760746c-8e96-4ef9-8d53-bf4428e18100");
    public const string BackGroundColorFieldName = "BackGroundColor";
    public static readonly ID HasBackgroundColorFieldId = new ID("b7fdfde1-258c-48a8-a934-3425a1c31494");
    public const string HasBackgroundColorFieldName = "HasBackgroundColor";

}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.TemplateIdString, Cachable=false)] 
public partial class ParametersTemplate_Panel : GlassBase, IParametersTemplate_Panel 
{
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
    [SitecoreField(IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.BackGroundColorFieldName)]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
    [SitecoreField(IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.HasBackgroundColorFieldName)]
    public virtual bool HasBackgroundColor {get; set;}
}
```

I've added a Droplink field to my template (figure 1.1) called BackGroundColor which points to a datasource that contains 3 items that have keys and values (figure 1.2).

**figure 1.1**
[image]

**figure 1.2**

[image]

I would like to get the selected item from the XP editor (figure 2.0) from my droplist so I can map its value (the color class name) to my model.

**figure 2.0**
[image]

It's not difficult for a checkbox or something similar but getting a selected item from a droplist seems to be a bit more challenging.
Any ideas on how I can make this happen using the current setup ( seeing as my models are being autogenerated)?

thanks.

Comment: You are using Droplink not Droplist, right? Try to get Item from Guid and then access properties

Comment: Yes, I am using a Droplink.  But I'm not getting the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to get the item through the `Guid`. There is a `Custom Data` property on the field (in this case `BackGroundColor`)  in Visual Studio, you can set this to the type of color and the code gen process would generate the property as this `Color` class instead of a `Guid`, so you will put something like this:

```
type=<optional namespace or global namespace>.Color
```

A more detailed walkthrough about the `Custom Data` property and `Code Generation` can be found [here](https://sitecorerunner.com/2017/10/13/so-that-is-what-the-custom-data-property-is-for-sitecore-hedgehog-tds-and-glass-mapper-model-generation/)

Comment: This look great. It works :).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom partial class for this template like the following:

```
public partial class ParametersTemplatePanel
{
     [SitecoreField(IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.BackGroundColorFieldName)]
     public virtual Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
     [SitecoreField(IParametersTemplate_PanelConstants.HasBackgroundColorFieldName)]
     public virtual bool HasBackgroundColor { get; set; }   
}
```

You add here a using to the generated Color template which has the Key-Value properties. After using this class you will have always acces for Key-Value.

to get this template you will need like the following to be called:

```
var parameters = sitecoreContext.GetItem<ParametersTemplatePanel>(id);
var backgroundKey = parameters.BackgroundColor.Key;
var backgroundValue = parameters.BackgroundColor.Value;
```